# Breaker temperature rating

Tags: electrical, electrical-panel

I am using a 100amp Stab Lok breaker in my main panel to power a subpanel in same area. The breaker I have says 40c. Is this ok or should it have a rating of 75c?

This is for 36” runs of 3 gauge to power sub panel.

Thanks.

Comment: See [How do I read circuit breaker temperature ratings?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/q/111063/35141). You may be misinterpreting what you're seeing and confusing trip calibration temps with wire ratings. Also show us a photo. That can clear things up in a hurry.

Comment: I was writing an answer, but can't now because this is Closed as a duplicate (legitimately so). **IMPORTANT: READ UP ON STAB-LOK PANELS. YOU ARE IN A POTENTIALLY DANGEROUS SITUATION.** See [this post](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/62320/should-all-federal-pacific-panels-be-replaced?rq=1) for details. Seriously consider either making the new subpanel into a main panel or replacing your main panel with another new panel.